# Is there a boilerpipe port for .net?

Tags: c#, .net, text-extraction, html-content-extraction, boilerpipe

Does anybody know a .net port for the [boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have ported boilerpipe 1.2 to .NET. It is available at GitHub: [NBoilerpipe](https://github.com/oganix/NBoilerpipe).

Comment: the code is tested in mono. but with a few correction works in c#. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at  [NReadability](https://github.com/marek-stoj/NReadability)

> NReadability cleans up hard-to-read articles on the Web. It's a tool for removing clutter from HTML pages so that they are more enjoyable to read.

Answer (score 1):

Some folks use IKVM to use the original boilerpipe on .NET:

*Voice Recognition + Content Extraction + TTS = Innovative Web Browsing
http://blog.databigbang.com/voice-recognition-content-extraction-tts-innovative-web-browsing/*

Comment: I have it working with IKVM/Mono on Mac, but unfortunately IKVM doesn't seems to run on MonoTouch.

Answer (score 0):

NBolierPipe is great! Here's the vanilla .NET port if interested.

https://github.com/adeperio/NBoilerpipe